# Using HashMap Iterator

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, iterator

I have two methods to iterate through a hash map containing a key(String) and a value(Arraylist) and add all the values from the Arraylists to a single Arraylist.

Method one did not work so I created Method two which fixed the issue but i'm not sure why method one did not work. Could someone please explain why method two works and method one does not?

**Method 1**

```
public ArrayList<Person> getPeopleList() 
{
    Iterator<ArrayList<Person>> iter = people.values().iterator();

    ArrayList<Person> allPersons = new ArrayList<>();
    while (iter.hasNext()) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iter.next().size(); i++) 
        {
            allPersons.add(iter.next().get(i));
        }

    }
    return allPersons;
}
```

**Method 2**

```
public ArrayList<Person> getPeopleList() 
{
    Iterator<ArrayList<Person>> iter = people.values().iterator();

    ArrayList<Person> allPersons = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Person> persons;
    while (iter.hasNext()) 
    {
        persons = iter.next();
        for (Person p : persons) 
        {
            allPersons.add(p);
        }

    }
    return allPersons;
}
```

Comment: should be posted on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AmitK Not quite, OP is asking about problem, not potential improvements for already working code.

Comment: never heard of it, why should it be posted their?

Comment: Method 1 is massively broken, as it's going to be calling `next()` *twice* per inner iteration, when it shouldn't be calling `iter.next()` at all - you want a single call to `iter.next()` per *outer* iteration.

Comment: @AmitK [*"Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets ... is off-topic for this site."*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Babyburger: Where is the OP iterating over `allPersons`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < iter.next().size(); i++)
```

This calls `next()` at each iteration of your for loop. You need to call it once, and store the result in a variable. Note that List has an `addAll()` method, making this for loop useless.

With streams, your whole code can be reduced to

```
return map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```